# How to use main application style in module without embedding with runtime style loading in flex 4 verion

Tags: css, apache-flex, module, skin

I want to load style runtime and apply to modules also.I don't want to embedd stye compile time. Modules not inherite style from main application. I have already loaded style runtime but style not visible in module mainly the font issue. Not able to use fonts which is embedded in CSS. Font size is very large.

Comment: Can you give any code examples?

Answer (score 1):

why not create an .swf font file which can be loaded in a module separately! or which also if needed will be used by the modules if placed in main index file! regards aktell

Comment: Its not possible because lots of fonts alreasy loaded dynamically(.swf). 6 to 7 modules is there so it will take time to load font for every modules, and other difficulty is i have used spark and mx component both in same component which font applying procedure is differ. I need to load style(css) dynamically which will use by every modules and application.

Comment: Well, if I'm honest I do not understand a word! I use hundreds of modules in one Application and have around 3 to 5 Fonts I'm using yet never all in one module only it differs a lot! so I would suggest to research this as there was a lot online and sure still is! regards aktell

Comment: Hi,
Let me give you some information.
I have one css file which has some style defined inside and two fonts emmbedded(for mx and Spark component).
I need to load style runtime based on client requirement.
I have already loaded that style using "StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(param)"
Other components emebedd style properly which is directly used in Mani application.
Labels,buttons and other components which is in different not able to use font from style sheet which is loaded runtime event compile time. Modules child not able to use Main application stylesheet font.

Comment: Thanks for your interest
Please let me know if any information require.